# Define (conditional) substitution rule for sum/difference of radicals

Tags: replacement, rule, conditional

I want to tell Mathematica to simplify some expressions applying the following substitutions, conditioned on the fact that $a\geq 0,b \geq 0, a^2-b\geq0 $

$$
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}} \pm \sqrt{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}  \ \to \ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{b}}
$$
or viceversa
$$
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} \pm \sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}} \ \to \ \sqrt{2}\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b}}
$$

How do I do that? I guess  I have to set a replacement rule but I do not know how to do that  in this case.

This could be used for example to simplify (assume $0 \leq k \leq 1$)

```
Sqrt[2 + k^4 + Sqrt[k^2 (8 + k^6)]] - Sqrt[2 + k^4 - Sqrt[k^2 (8 + k^6)]]
```

in `Sqrt[2]Sqrt[2+k^4 - Sqrt[4 (1-k^2)^2]]`, and then (possibly) in `Sqrt[2] k Sqrt[k^2 + 2]`.

Also, what if the original expression (given by MMA) is

```
Sqrt[2 + k^4 + k Sqrt[8 + k^6]] - Sqrt[2 + k^4 - k Sqrt[8 + k^6]]
```

can we use the same rule?

As a side note,

```
Assuming [0 <= k <= 1, (Sqrt[2 + k^4 + Sqrt[k^2 (8 + k^6)]] - Sqrt[2 + k^4 - Sqrt[k^2 (8 + k^6)]]) == (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 + k^4 - Sqrt[4 (1 - k^2)^2]]) // FullSimplify]
```

does not return `True`, even though the terms are non negative (within the assumptions) and their squares are equal, i.e.

```
Assuming [0 <= k <= 1,(Sqrt[2 + k^4 + Sqrt[k^2 (8 + k^6)]] - Sqrt[2 + k^4 - Sqrt[k^2 (8 + k^6)]])^2 == (Sqrt[2] k Sqrt[k^2 + 2])^2 // FullSimplify]
```

returns `True`.